# How can I send a file's contents as a POST parameter using cURL?

Tags: linux, bash, http, post, curl

I'm trying to use cURL to POST the contents of a file, as if I'd pasted that contents in to an html textarea.  That's to say I don't want to upload the file, I just want a post parameter called foo to be filled with text from a file called bar.txt.  bar.txt's contents may include newlines, quotes, and so on.

Is this possible?

Thanks.

Edit:  I found out how to do it in the end:

```
curl --data-urlencode "foo@bar.txt" http://example.com/index.php
```

This will take the contents of the file bar.txt, url encode it, place the resultant string in a parameter called foo in a POST request of http://example.com/index.php.

I can't speak to whether the solutions others have suggested will work or not, but the one above seems like the best way.

Comment: I don't know how to mark this as solved, but it is.

Comment: you can answer your own question and then select it.  I found your answer to be the only that actually works

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can by doing something like:

```
$ curl --data "foo:$(cat foo.txt)" http://localhost/yourfile.php
```

Note that you'll probably want to encode the file, as cacheguard said. To encode it in base64, just modify the previous command like this:

```
$ curl --data "foo:$(cat foo.txt | base64)" http://localhost/yourfile.php
```

Answer (score 0):

You should encode/decode the content of your file (for instance by using the base64 command under Linux).

file foo.txt:

```
8<----------------------------
Hello World
I am a Secure Web Gateway
8<----------------------------
```

```
base64 foo.txt | base64 -d
```